# Simple jquery function isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm stumped. I added a simple jquery function to the footer.php of my wordpress theme, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I tried an even simpler hide(); function and that didn't fire either. I can't get any jquery to fire at all, but the jquery library is definitely loading into my theme (it's based on twentyeleven). Here's my code:

```
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
</div><!-- #page -->

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".sub-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
}); 
</script>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I loaded the jquery ui core effects via my functions.php and see that it shows up in the site's resources when I use the Chrome inspector, so the highlight(); function should work.

[Here's the page it should be working on](http://www.mcnettfamily.org/wedding/our-story/)

Why wouldn't the jquery script be running?

Thanks!

Kenny

**EDIT**

Final code is the following (Sadly, I don't know how to make the effect recursive through the `<li>` elements, but this does the job):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li:first-child').animate({ marginRight: '15px' }, 500);
    $('.sub-menu li:first-child').animate({ marginRight: '0' }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(2)').animate({ marginRight: '15px' }, 500);
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(2)').animate({ marginRight: '0' }, 500);
    }, 400);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(3)').animate({ marginRight: '15px' }, 500);
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(3)').animate({ marginRight: '0' }, 500);
    }, 800);
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(4)').animate({ marginRight: '15px' }, 500);
    $('.sub-menu li:nth-child(4)').animate({ marginRight: '0' }, 500);
    }, 1200);
}, 3000);

}(jQuery)); 
</script>
```

Comment: Try running `$(function() {console.log(typeof jQuery);});` to see if it's loaded, so as to check if really is'nt loading, or if the problem is the invalid document.ready function,

Comment: And you're not that there's no JavaScript error?

Comment: The line `$(".sub-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);` is being run. Try taking out the `$` in `function($)`, or adding `(jQuery)` after the closing curly braces on the next line.

Comment: I added (jQuery) after the closing curly braces and the function ran. Big thx @andrewap. Also, I used blackcatweb's solution of replacing  '.effect()' with 'animate' because '.effect()' threw an error.

Comment: @adrewap, not sure how to give you credit for your answer. the `(jQuery)` addition was the ticket.

Comment: @Kenny You're welcome. I see that you've posted new code for your animation. I've added an answer to explain the `(jQuery)` part, and a suggestion for simplifying your code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is not running because the `$` argument is not defined. The solution is to add `(jQuery)` after the closing curly braces:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".sub-menu").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
}(jQuery));
```

This technique is used when multiple libraries (potentially ones that also use `$`) are present. See [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery) for details.

Now, it looks like you want to animate the `sub-menu` list items one by one with a 400 ms delay. You can simplify your code by using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // iterate over li in .sub-menu
    // NOTE: the overall initial delay is 3000 ms
    $('.sub-menu li').delay(3000).each(function (i) {

        // the effect sets margin-right to 15px, then to 0 after completion
        // NOTE: the delay increases by 400 ms for each item
        $(this).delay(i * 400).animate({ marginRight: '15px' }, 500, 'linear', function () {
            // this is the 'complete' callback function
            $(this).animate({ marginRight: '0' }, 500);
        });

    });

}(jQuery));
```

The second part of the animation (setting `margin-right` to 0) is defined in the `complete` argument of `.animate()`, which eliminates one `.animate()` call. The `i * 400` delay creates the cascading effect that you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like '.effect()' doesn't do anything to any element on your page.  I haven't figured out why (I thought it was a CSS evaluation order problem originally, but it's not).

Is this an acceptable alternative?

```
$('.sub-menu').animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffff99' }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks blackcatweb. I don't know why the `.effect()` doesn't do anything either, but your idea of using `.animate` got me going in a good direction.